# How to simulate onclick (JavaScript) using Selenium/Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am using Python/Selenium to click on an icon on a web site which downloads a file. I know how to click on regular buttons using Selenium but this one is a bit tricky as it's not a regular button and it's making a Javascript call. I've tried several find_element_by calls but was unable to access this element. Can anyone think of a way to click on this using a selenium call?

When I do inspect element for the download icon in my web browser this is what I get:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="pull-right margin-r" onclick="
                        document.theForm.action='/p1234/DownloadData';
                        $('#theForm').append($('<input>', {type:'hidden', name:'Download', value:'Download'})).submit();
                    "><img src="/images/download.png" title="Download" alt="Download" style="" border="0"></a>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about locating the element by the part of the `onclick` attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*=DownloadData]").click();
```

where `*=` means "contains".