# Selecting a Button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and I am trying to figure out how to simulate a onclick,
this is what I see in the source code when I inspect the html source:

```
 <div class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="bbb_view_results" onclick="showResults();" style="">View Results</div>
```

I tried following but nothing worked:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary#bbb_view_results[onclick*='showResults()']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[36]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]").click()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-sm btn-primary.bbb_view_results").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.btn btn-sm btn-primary').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('bbb_view_results').click()
```

Almost all of the error messages were NoSuchElementException. 
Some of the error messages:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="bbb_view_results"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[text()='View Results']"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.btn btn-sm btn-primary"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate onclick (JavaScript) using Selenium/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959718/how-to-simulate-onclick-javascript-using-selenium-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python + Selenium: How can click on “onclick” elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171370/python-selenium-how-can-click-on-onclick-elements)

Comment: First you want to "select the element" then you can `.click()` it. Something like `elem = driver.find_element_by_id('bbb_view_results'); elem.click()`

Comment: When you  said "nothing worked", what do you mean?  It failed silently?  There was a selenium error of some kind?

Comment: @orde most of it were NoSuchElementException. I have edited  my question and also included the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-sm.btn-primary').click()
```

and also

```
driver.find_element_by_id('bbb_view_results').click()
```

should work fine.
but maybe you need to change to other frame, can you post the full page_source or url?

**UPDATED:**

After seeing your desired url for **scraping** data;

You need to switch frame to be able to click the button.
The proper way to click it after the whole data loaded is by using the modules:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

something like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'instance-283000-header')))
```

But, i couldn't get them work in there - so i used sleep for demonstration.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.flexmls.com/cgi-bin/mainmenu.cgi?cmd=url+other/createlink/link_receiver.html&' \
      'no_html_header=true&i=rgsmmct2qgk,12'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame('publiclinkpanel')
sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-sm.btn-primary').click()
sleep(10)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: original site: https://www.mlssaz.com/public_search.html                                          frame: https://www.flexmls.com/cgi-bin/mainmenu.cgi?cmd=url+other/createlink/link_receiver.html&no_html_header=true&i=rgsmmct2qgk,12